# VSTO outlook add-in - Retrieve sender's name for reply

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am going through the walkthrough on how to create your first outlook addin using the ribbon designer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019

My goal is to make reply templates that includes the sender's name in the greeting.

From researching the issue, I believe I need either `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` or `MailItem.Sender` but when I tried to add it to the `mailitem.htmlbody` it doesn't show anything at all.

Here is the code I have for my test.

```
 private void Teser_button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer() != null)
                {
                    MailItem mi = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse;
                    if (mi != null)
                    {

                        mi.HTMLBody = mi.SenderEmailAddress + @"<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri></BODY>Hello ENTERNAMEHERE,
<br><
<br>Here is a brief summary on everything worked on:
<br>
<br>Thank you for your time,
<br>
" + mi.HTMLBody;
                        mi.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried changing `mi.SenderEmailAddress` to `mi.Sender` but I still get nothing.

Any ideas are appreciated!!

Updated

Here is code that worked for me for both the outlook explorer, and from a popup (Its not the best but it works):

```
 private void Domain_setup_Click_1(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer() != null)
            {
                MailItem mi = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse;
                Outlook.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
                object item = selection[1];
                if (mi != null && item is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
                {
                    string senderName = mailItem.SenderName;
                    mi.HTMLBody = @"<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri></BODY>Hello " + senderName + @",
<br>
<br>Here is the information for the new domain/user account:
<br>
<br>Computer username: ENTERDOMAINORUSERNAMEHERE
<br>Computer password: ENTERPASSWORD
<br>
<br>Thank you for your time,
<br>
" + mi.HTMLBody;
                }
            }
            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector() != null)
            {
                MailItem mi = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
                Outlook.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
                object item = selection[1];
                if (mi != null && item is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
                {
                    string senderName = mailItem.SenderName;
                    mi.HTMLBody = @"<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri></BODY>Hello " + senderName + @",
<br>
<br>Here is the information for the new domain/user account:
<br>
<br>Computer username: ENTERDOMAINORUSERNAMEHERE
<br>Computer password: ENTERPASSWORD
<br>
<br>Thank you for your time,
<br>
" + mi.HTMLBody;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the sender name on the reply, not the message being replied to. The name should come from the first item in the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection` collection.

```
Outlook.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
if (selection.Count > 0)
{
  object item = selection[1];
  if (item is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
  {
    string senderName = mailItem.SenderName;
  }
}
```

Also, you cannot and should not concatenate two HTML strings - the result will **not** be a valid HTML document, the two must be merged (e.g. you can insert your HTML after the end of the `<body>` tag in `mi.HTMLBody`).

Comment: I tried using `testvare = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().sender;` but I get an error saying: `type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I also tried using `testvar = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer.sender;` but I got another error saying `Application.ActiveExplorer is a method, which is not valid in the given context.`

Comment: This actually worked - but I should have been more detailed. You see, I only gave half of the function because I thought it wasn't as import.

You see..I actually was using both `ActiveExplorer()` and `ActiveInspector()` so that I can make a reply from the outlook explorer or from a popout window. Your code works but only with outlook explorer which makes sense because that was the only thing I asked for. hahaha I tried seeing if `ActiveInspector().selection` is a thing and it doesn't seem like it. I will mark your answer as correct and see if I can learn from this. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new item in an inspector, things are trickier - you don't know where the reply you are working with (in `ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`) came from. It could be another inspector where the original item was displayed, or it could come from an item selected in an `Explore`r. To handle both, you'd need to trap the `Explorer.SelectionChange` and `Inspectors.NewInspector` events and set up `Reply/ReplyAll/Forward` event handlers on the original item. When the event fires, you'll have both the old item and the new item (passed as a parameter).

Comment: I made some code that seems to work. I added it to the make post since I can't make multiline comments here

Answer (score 0):

The sender-related properties exist on the received items. So, what you actually need is to get the source item being replied to. To avoid unnecessary searching for the original email you can use several ways to retrieve the required information in Outlook:

1. You can hook up to the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.reply?view=outlook-pia) event of Outlook items, so when a user chooses to reply to an email you will get all the required information and paste to the message body. You may find the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article helpful. An instance of the response object is passed as a parameter, so you can modify the message body with the sender-related information extracted from the event source.
2. If the item is saved and was sent/received, you can use the [GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method to obtain a [Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation) object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. A conversation represents one or more items in one or more folders and stores. If you move an item in a conversation to the `Deleted Items` folder and subsequently enumerate the conversation by using the `GetChildren`, `GetRootItems`, or `GetTable` method, the item will not be included in the returned object.